# Redirect to specific page

Tags: wp-redirect

I am using **Wp Store Locator** plugin.And I have Modified it according my need.But I am stuck in redirection.

Basically this plugin works with short code.So at the time of listing my URL is like that : `localhost/wordpress/?page_id=391`

Now there is one link which is redirects me to `http://localhost/wordpress/?wpsl_id=3`

Here is code for that :

```
    add_action("template_redirect", 'my_theme_redirect');

    function my_theme_redirect() {

            $dpath = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ;
        $templatefilename = 'single-store.php';
        if (strpos($dpath,'wpsl_id') !== false){    
                $return_template = get_template_directory() .'/' .$templatefilename  ;
                //$nurl = get_permalink($return_template);
                //echo $return_template; exit;
                wp_redirect($return_template);

                exit;               
            }
    }
```

This code is not redirecting me to any-where.It stays on the same page **localhost/wordpress/?page_id=391** What might be the issue?